# Can not send call log as message using SMSmanager Android

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent, calllog

I used intent and pending intent to send message. The code is working fine when I sent  some texts.
The problem is that, while sending call logs as String by sms manger it never send it.

I can send simple text messages using this code but when i adding the string which copies call log it do not send the message.

I have given call log permission and send and receive sms permissions in manifest.

My code is here :-

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sendmessage;


import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
 import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void sendme(View v)
{


    Cursor mCursor=managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int number=mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int date=mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration=mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int type=mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

    while (mCursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String phnumber=mCursor.getString(number);
        String callduration=mCursor.getString(duration);
        String calltype=mCursor.getString(type);
        String calldate=mCursor.getString(date);


        Date mDate = null;
        //---------------------------------------------------
        String givenDateString = calldate;// dateTime variable is the variable in which you are storing the date currently
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0530"));
        try {
            mDate = (Date) sdf.parse(givenDateString);
          //  timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------
   //   Date d=new Date(calldate);
        String callTypeStr="";

        switch (Integer.parseInt(calltype)) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
         callTypeStr="OutGoing";
        break;

        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            callTypeStr="Incoming";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            callTypeStr="Missed";
            break;
        }


        sb.append("Phone Number" + phnumber);
        sb.append("Call duration" + callduration);
        sb.append("call type" + callTypeStr);
        sb.append("Date" + mDate);
        sb.append("------------------------------");
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);  
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);  

    //Get the SmsManager instance and call the sendTextMessage method to send message                 
    SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    sms.sendTextMessage("9074560566", null, sb.toString().substring(0, 500), pi,null); 

  }

  }
```

kindly please give a solution.

Comment: The `sendTextMessage()` method will fail – usually silently – if your message length exceeds the character limit. You'll need to use the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method instead. It works for regular, single-part messages, too, so you don't need to bother with checking the length yourself.

Comment: it has asking permission as sending a large number of Sms messages. is it possible to remove this popup

Comment: Nope, not really. At least, not on an un-rooted device.